# Keyboard shown only on double tapping entry

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have an entry in xaml as follows :

```
<Entry x:name="userNameEntry" Placeholder="Name"/>
```

In my xaml.cs file I have written the following code in page's constructor:

```
userNameEntry.Focused += (sender, e) =>
{
userNameEntry.Placeholder = "";
}
```

Whenever I tap the entry field the placeholder text is replaced but the keyboard isn't shown. I have to tap again to bring up the keyboard.

How do I replace the placeholder and show the keyboard?

Comment: Why are you removing the placeholder text? It goes away on it's own and shows again when the field is empty.

Comment: the placeholder is removed only when i start typing. I want the placeholder to be removed when the entry is focused.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is kind of race condition here. So I think you need to Implement the onFocus event from Xaml and handle it from the code behind.

```
<Entry x:name="userNameEntry" Placeholder="Name" Focused="userNameEntry_OnFocused"/>
```

and in the code behind

```
 private void userNameEntry_OnFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
 {
    userNameEntry.Placeholder = "";
 }
```

Try that if it would work :) Although myself I would not remove the placeholder before the user starts typing because that is would it simply works .

Comment: thanks for replying. But same thing is happening, the keyboard pops up only on double tap.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the scenario you find. By checking the [EntryRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/EntryRenderer.cs) of the xamarin form source code we can find that

`_textView.Hint = Element.Placeholder;`

the `Hint` property is from android native `EditText`, and the renderer target object is [EntryEditText](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/EntryEditText.cs) that is inherit from `EditText` in android native.

So I have created a project of xamarin android and use the EditText with hint as the following code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    EditText et;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        et = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.edittext);
        et.Click += Et_Click; 
    }

    private void Et_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        et.Hint = "";
    }
}
```

When I click the EditText the keyboard shows and at the same time the hint disappeared.

I also created the customer renderer of the Entry as the following code:

**the portable code**

```
public class MyEditText : View
{

}
```

**the android project code**

```
public class MyEditTestRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyEditText, EditText>,Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener
{
    EditText et;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyEditText> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            // perform initial setup
            et = new EditText(this.Context);
            SetNativeControl(et);
        }
        et.Click += Et_Click; 
        et.Hint = "name";
       // et.SetOnClickListener(this);

    }
    private void Et_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        et.Hint = "";
    }
}
```

But it can not detect the click event when I first click the `EditText`. The `Hint`  disappeared when I second click the `EditText`.

You can report this issue to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/